# Why WETH contract use src, dst, wad instead of from, to, values?

Tags: contract-development, transferfrom, wrapped-tokens

When I read WETH9 contract code, I felt strange.

For example, generally "transferFrom" method has "from", "to", "value" as parameters but WETH9's transferFrom has "src", "dst", "wad".

Why is this happening?

WETH9 contract code:
https://github.com/makerdao/sai/blob/master/src/weth9.sol